# VueJS PWA's - Enabling Workbox "debug" via GenerateSW

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin, vue-pwa

When using `GenerateSW` to build your WorkBox `service-worker.js` there are a number of configurations for which consistent documentation is hard to find.

Many problems can be overcome with the Workbox debug mode enabled in the `service-worker.js`:

```
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true
});
```

How does one get `npm run build` to add this line to the `service-worker.js` automatically?

My current config is:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '',
  pwa: {
    // General config bits.. 
    name: '...',

    // Configuration of the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW',
    workboxOptions: {

      // ** Would like to flag DEBUG here!? **
      // debug: true,

      // ...Further example Workbox options...
      skipWaiting: true,
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: new RegExp('https://fonts.(gstatic|googleapis).*'),
          handler: 'cacheFirst',
          method: 'GET',
          options: {cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}}
        },
      ],
    }
  }
};
```

*Note, just adding the `setConfig` line to the `service-worker.js` (post-build) does what I need.. but it's tedious and must be unnecessary?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If/when [Vue's PWA plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa) is updated to use Workbox v5, that should be possible by setting `mode: 'development'` in your [GenerateSW config](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW).

In the meantime, you could put that into a `wb-debug.js` file that's deployed alongside your service worker, and then add `importScripts: ['wb-debug.js']` into your configuration.

Or just script something in the `webpack` build process to automatically append that to the end of the generated service worker, like you appear to be currently doing.